# Store Core Data Sqlite in NSLibraryDirectory or NSApplicationSupportDirectory?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, path, synchronization

What is the difference between NSLibraryDirectory and NSApplicationSupportDirectory? Which one is the best place to store the Core Data .sqlite file if I am planning on using a syncing service?

I currently store my .sqlite file in NSLibraryDirectory. If NSApplicationSupportDirectory turns out to be the better choice, how will changing this affect my current users? Can it easily be changed, and what are the steps I should take to ensure a seamless transition for my existing users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If doesn't matter for syncing service where you store your data file. But if you will change its location then you have to move your data file of previous users to new location.

Comment: Why would I choose to store the document in one place vs. another? For example, what does it mean to store a document in NSLibraryDirectory vs. NSApplicationSupportDirectory? How are they different?